# Cannot open a SQL connection to a SQL Server: The network path was not found

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I am developing a .NET based web application and I want to connect to a SQL Server, which I created using SQL Server Management Studio 2014. I already followed tutorials from [ITWorld](https://www.itworld.com/article/3007292/development/how-to-create-sql-server-connection-strings-in-visual-studio.html) and [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program) with no success. I got an error *"Network Path was not found"*. Although when I test it on Project Properties - > Settings -> Connection Properties, The result is "Test Connection succeeded". Executing Query directly via SQL Management Studio works too.

How do I fix this problem?

**Web.config**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQL_Server"
      connectionString="Data Source=192.168.60.130;Initial Catalog=TestServer;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=name;Password=password"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            string sqlConn = "SQL_Server";
            ConnectionStringSettings settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[sqlConn];

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(settings.ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open(); //this is line 31 as shown from the Stack Trace error below
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from [SQL_DB].[dbo].[users]", conn);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(reader);
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
            }
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]

[SqlException (0x80131904): Network-related or instance-specific error when connecting to SQL Server. The server was not found or can not be accessed. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server allows remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open connection with SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +1431
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1085
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +964
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +109
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1529
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +156
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +258
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +312
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +202
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +413
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +128
   VF.BC._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\VM_User\source\repos\SQLProject\Default.aspx.cs:31
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +106
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3785
```

Comment: Try to give a normal name to the connection string

Comment: Check with debugger, what is value of: settings.ConnectionString. Is it the same what you have written in configuration file?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I changed with a shorter name. Still got same error

Comment: @User2018 call it "examplename" and try again

Comment: @RistoM Yes it's the same

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Still the same error.

Comment: I added the stack trace error

Comment: This is the part of the error that is useful: `Network-related or instance-specific error when connecting to SQL Server. The server was not found or can not be accessed. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server allows remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open connection with SQL Server)]`

Comment: Is the web server, management studio, and the SQL Server all on the same machine? What does _I haven't change the Firewall settings because I'm not sure I'm allowed to change them_ mean? This is a network issue so we need to understand the network situation

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The Web Server and the SQL Server are on different machines (192.168.60.130 and 192.168.60.131). I'm not sure because this is a work project code. Not a personal project.

Comment: First thing to do is change the connection string to force tcp (not names pipes) like this: `Data Source=tcp:192.168.60.130;Initial Catalog=TestServer;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=name;Password=password`. Then you need to ensure the web server can connect to the SQL Server. This is difficult to troubleshoot in this manner. You need to ask an admin at your work to ensure that the web server can connect to the SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many causes of this error message which are given below

- Antivirus,
- Firewall
- SQL Server Network configuration

Please check if you have the port in the connection string "Data Source=x.x.x.x,1433"

For detail, please check this video. [Resolving SQL Server Connection Errors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1k00z82u4OI)

Comment: The SQL Server is running. I have changed the settings in SQL Server Configuration Manager, but I still got the same error. I haven't change the Firewall settings because I'm not sure I'm allowed to change them.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It should work. Did you try to access using management studio

Comment: I tried already with SQL management studio and it works too. Test connection via Connection Properties also succeeded.

Comment: Did you try with port 1433?  "Data Source=192.168.60.130, 1433;

Comment: I created the firewall rule and test with port 1433. Now I got an error: The wait operation timed out. I tried also with "MultiSubnetFailover=True".

Comment: Add following in connection string Network Library=DBMSSOCN;

Answer (score 1):

So I finally found the issue. The issue was actually the firewall between the web server and the SQL server. I just realized that they are on a completely different IP address. I tested using a [UDL Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/steverac/2010/12/13/test-remote-sql-connectivity-easily/) and the web server could not access the SQL server.

I contacted the Network admin and the issue is now resolved.

I should have tested this way earlier. Thank you everyone here for your time and support. Sorry for causing confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There is noting wrong with your code, It should work. Please check your network setting and access rights. I had the same problem after wasting hours on that I found that it was my antivirus. In short it can be network port or firewall.

Comment: Hi @A to Z Tak, Welcome to StackOverflow! This question was already answered a long time ago. So you might continue contributing on other unanswered questions :). Thank you anyway for your answer! And yes, Firewall was the issue.

Comment: I miss that answer. Thank you for your comment .

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:-

```
string connectionString = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL_Server"].ConnectionString.ToString();

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@connectionString);
```

Let me know if this helps.